# Amazon CloudFront to serve dynamic Vue.js Build flies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Amazon ec2 server, 53 DNS, and my website is hosted at namecheap (with ssl).
I figured that since Vue build files are usually big and they take much time to download, it'd be better if I could serve them using a CDN server.
However, these are not static files, in the sense that every time that I change my Vue source code and build and upload to my server, the files' content change and so do their names.
So is there an option for a CDN that searches for files and then serves them if they are found?

I've read everywhere S3 being mentioned along with CloudFront, but it seems that it only supports specific files upload, and uploading my Vue build files everytime I change my code is inconvenient.

Comment: Hi. Why do you think uploading my Vue build files everytime I change my code is not reasonable?

Comment: Because I may change them every other day.

Comment: From your development environment, you can automate the sync process with a simple command to the S3 and also invalidate the CloudFront cache. Thats one of the patterns to do for deployments. If this approach works for you, I can update the answer with details.

Comment: *"these are not static files, in the sense that every time that I change my Vue source code and build and upload to my server, the files' content change and so do their names."*  Those still sound like static files.  A static file is pretty much any file whose contents are rendered before (not after) the browser requests it, and whose content doesn't vary from request to request of the same filename.

Answer (score 0):

Configure TTL as 0 in CloudFront for this image. You have option to configure a different TTL for different paths in origin.

CloudFront will not cache the files if the content is changed with a TTL of 0. For all incoming requests, CloudFront will check with origin if there is a change in the file contents and will automaoically refresh it's cache if the original content changes.

This should be an ideal TTL value for dynamically generated contents. If you think that the file would change infrequently, you can perhaps configure the TTL to a bit higher value.